# How To Identify Compile Error With Split Value

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have got through every compile error post on the site and I know it has something to do with the `.Value`. I have tried setting it to `= Now` and adding `(Now, term.Value)` similar to what others have done. Does anyone see why I'm getting the "Compile error: Method or data member not found"

Please let me know if you see anything wrong specifically with the `words() = Split(term.Value)` code:

```
Sub FindSimilar()
    Dim phrases As Range, phrase As Range
    Dim terms As Range, term As Range
    Dim matches As String
    Dim words() As String

    'ensure this has the correct sheet names for your workbook
    Set phrases = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("B2:B4345")
    Set terms = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Topics").Range("D1847:D4847")

    For Each term In terms
        matches = ""
        words() = Split(term.Value)


        For i = 0 To UBound(words, 1)
        If Len(words(i)) > 2 Then
         Select Case words(i)
          Case "business", "example", "string"
          Case Else
            For Each phrase In phrases
                If InStr(1, phrase.Value, words(i)) Then
                    matches = matches & phrase & "/"
                End If
            Next phrase
         End Select
        End If
        Next i

        If matches <> vbNullString Then
            term.Offset(0, 6).Value = Left(matches, Len(matches) - 1)
        Else
            term.Offset(0, 6).Value = "No match"
        End If
    Next term
End Sub
```

Also, as a note, this code was working well and it just stopped working so I'm assuming it's just an update or some small text. I'm using Excel for Mac.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: `Sub FindSimilar()` and `words() = Split(term.Value)` - specifically at `Value`

Comment: The function Split takes two parameters, but you're only passing one.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ the delimiter is optional.

Comment: @BigBen I hadn't realized that :) good call.

Comment: @BigBen yeah, just figured out. I wouldn't omit it though, default values are evil :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I agree with you :)

Comment: I think @BigBen is right, this must be a problem at the modular level - OP should copy and paste the entire module here.

Comment: Can't replicate the error with the code you've provided.

Comment: Do you have any other code in the module/workbook? If you paste just this code into a new workbook with the same sheets, do you get the same error?

Comment: when you get the error, what is returned in the immediate window if you type `?term.address` and `? term.value`?

Comment: It says syntax error....btw I just ran it on a windows install of excel and it worked fine.

Comment: BOTH lines return `syntax error`?

Comment: Which one?  I suggested two lines to type in the immediate window, so I don't know which one you are referring to.

Comment: It was this line: `?term.value`

Comment: What did the other line return?

Comment: shoudln't it be `words = Split(...)`, is `words() = Split(...)` even valid syntax?